# Django-cms show_breadcrumb template tag

Tags: django, django-cms, templatetags

Where is located django-cms `{% show_breadcrumb %}` tag? I looked all over templatetags in cms app, but didn't find it.

Comment: you need some R & D.you will get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is defined in `django-cms/menus/templatetags/menu_tags.py`. [See on github](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templatetags/menu_tags.py#L249).